# another sql query statement

Tags: c#, sql

ok thanks alot for all who help me ,but now i have another problem i want to get this statement correct also

```
if (byNametextBox.Text != null && byBuildingtextBox.Text !=null && seTextBoxPublic1.Text == null)
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name='" +     byNametextBox.Text +"and [buil-id]='"+byBuildingtextBox.Text+ "'", MyConn);

}
```

i want to select from the same table with two condition
please

Comment: Do *not* build up query strings like this. Use parameterized queries, otherwise you're wide open for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Please use parameters! If for some reason you're against them, this should work:

```
string strStatement = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE [name] = '{0}' AND [buil-id] = '{1}'", byNametextBox.Text, byBuildingtextBox.Text);
da = new SqlDataAdapter(strStatement, MyConn);
```

Comment: This isn't parameters. You're still creating a string, it's almost the same.

Comment: Yes Kobi, but like I said if for some reason he's AGAINST using parameters, the code I posted WILL work (his source code was formatted incorrectly and would not).

Comment: Well, yes. Defiantly, this is a cleaner syntax for that.

Answer (score 1):

Better for security if you use parameters in your SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should create an SqlCommand with 2 parameters.
The code you posted here is not safe for SQL Injection attacks.

Please follow:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, however, your code creates the SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name='NAMEand [buil-id]='ID'
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name='NAME' and [buil-id]='ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parameterized` query to prevent sql injection, also here some additional codes if you want to populate datatable.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name = @byName and [buil-id]= @byBuilding " , MyConn)
                           DataTable dt= new DataTable();
                            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@byName", byNametextBox.Text); 
                            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@byBuilding", byBuildingtextBox.Text);
                           da.Fill(dt);
```